# How can I split digits and text from a string with a Regex?

Tags: regex, string, parsing

#### I'm having a little problem parsing a text

I have a wrong written text that has text and numbers joined sometimes in some words.

For example this:

```
I have3 games in my2 computers!
```

I'm looking for a Regex that can transform it to get the right text, in this case it would look like this:

```
I have 3 games in my 2 computers!
```

> Tip: text can contain special characters like **/**, **-**, *****, etc

Comment: Do you have anything you have written that doesn't work?

Comment: Please take the time to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you were trying to say Dadani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the number after modified. Make the number has whitespaces on both side. It can be done using Regex variable `$1` for value in `()`

```
s.replace(/\s*([0-9]+)\s*/i, " $1 ");
```

Comment: It's a good idea to process all groups of digits, but keep in mind that doing this may add unwanted leading or trailing spaces when the digits start or end the string.

Comment: Yup, you have to trim the whitespaces. But I think he gets the point.

Comment: It's a good approach but it doesn't seems to return what is expected. Try running it in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work,

```
var matches = "your-string".match(/[a-zA-Z!]+|[0-9]+/g);
console.log(matches.join(" "));
```

Comment: Why not this approach, but it assumes that the string only contains letters, digits, spaces, and exclamation marks and assumes too that a space is needed between a punctuation sign (for example) and a digit.

Comment: I think I can use this approach by adding to the regex the special characters I need to the regex, don't you think?